# Method available in project but not in playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift-playground

I'm new to Swift - using Swift 3, Xcode 8.0 beta 6, Mac OS X 10.11.6.  The following line works in my project (it's a simple test case to see if the 'contains' method is working):

```
if ("hello John".contains("John")){}
```

It works fine in my project, but when I cut and paste it into a playground project, it gives an error:

> "Value of type 'String' has no member 'contains'".

My question is, apart from why this error is being thrown, are there different frameworks/functions/methods etc. being used in playground projects from normal projects?
Thanks for your help.
Squire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Playgrounds you may miss some framework - you need to import framework too, to be able to access its methods:

like

```
import Foundation // responsible for strings for example
```

or

```
import UIKit // responsible for UI elements
```

... etc

[image]

Comment: Thanks pedrouan, that solved it.  I had assumed (wrongly!) that the .contains method was part of the same framework as .hasPrefix (which was working ok in the function).  Unfortunately, until the 'import Foundation' statement was included, no quick help documenation is available on any of the functions therein.  Bit of a flaw - would be nice to have the context-sensitive help on functions available regardless of whether or not the framework containing those functions is imported.  Anway, thanks for your help.  I'll plod on to my next blunder now! :)

Comment: You are welcome. It's true, I had the same feeling when met that problem before. Compiler does not suggest any framework to use and we cannot use basic methods without one.